# Permissions Numbers Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Going through with permissions and understanding permissions, I understand thats the 3 is not part of the owner, group, other. I also know that 7 is the highest permission for those three sets, what is the 9 in the permissions set (3907)?

-rw-------.  1 root root       3907 Mar  4 08:34 sshd_config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tilman stated the 3907 is file size.
The permissions are shown as -rw-------.

This case rw- --- --- would be I believe 600 in permissions.  Which would be file owner can read and write it.  Groups and Other can not do anything.

You can read up a bit here, seems to be a nice little break down of it:

https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Comment: thank you that resource. sorry for the noob question. I am currently taking a course for Linux+ and doing a lab on a VM. I appreciate the help

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere.  Also you will continously learn stuff about stuff you thought you knew to.  (chmod -c... might be useful and I did not know that was a thing)

Answer (score 1):

The `3907` in your `ls -l` output is not the permissions but the file size in bytes.

The permissions are the part `-rw------` which in numeric representation would be `0600`, meaning read and write permission for the owner (`root`) only.

Comment: so then what are the permissions for the owner group other from that line after putting in the command "ls -l /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: As long as I am not crazy today
r = 4
w = 2
x = 1
So 600 = rw- --- ---

Comment: so with that, the command "ls -l /var/log/cro" is the same permissions written out as...

-rw-------. 1 root root 3442 Mar 4 08:34 /var/log/cron

the permissions would still be r+w for owner, none for group, none for other correct?